# Should we encourage all users to post code in code-blocks instead of pictures?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

On occasion, on SO and here, posters will post there code as pictures and not in code-blocks. As a group, should we encourage or discourage this practice?

Answer (score 17):

In my view, we should discourage it where they are looking for someone to improve their code. If the look of the screen is important and can't be replicated (easily) in StackExchange's own formatting, a screenshot would be fine as long as the relevant code is also provided as code blocks.

Comment: If it is a question about formatting, then I'm fine with the picture; it's evidence, after all. So, I agree.

Comment: Sometimes pasted code in markedown is just unreadible, especially when a lot of special characters are present. I agree that in these cases both code and picture may/should be posted. Perhaps we could put the code in the description of the picture (the stuff in the markdown code that ends up being the anchor of the picture link)?

Answer (score 10):

"If your code is intended to be executed by the people supposed to help you, make it copyable."