# Representation of special symbols in posted code blocks

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Since [we have decided that pasted code is favorable to pasted images of code](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/should-we-encourage-all-users-to-post-code-in-code-blocks-instead-of-pictures), I think there's another issue to resolve: *How* should the code be pasted? A good examle are Greek letters. A code sprinkled with `\[CurlyTheta]` is very hard to read in "copy as plain text" form.

Now while I think it may be too much to ask people do this themselves every time, my question is of more concern to people with edit rights: are we encouraged to edit those posts, replacing things like `\[CurlyTheta]` with something like `th` for easier readability?

Answer (score 9):

I'd say the chance of breaking something by accident is too big (it *will* happen without doubt), and most people will paste the code back to Mathematica anyway.  Also, `\[Alpha]` is not *that* unreadable (I've been fine with it on SO).  It's not the same as these things:

```
\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(f[x, y]\)\)
```

which are truly unreadable.

I vote to leave these alone, and not edit them, *unless* the code is really terribly unreadable.

Comment: Personally, the `\[UndirectedEdge]`s in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/356/vertexsize-doesnt-scale-with-graph-layout drives me nuts...

Comment: @Brett Well, you're right about that. I wonder why `<->` isn't produced when converting yo InputForm, after all it's accepted as input!

Comment: @Szabolcs is that true?  Can I edit `\[UndirectedEdge]` to `<->` and preserve code integrity?  (Side note: you can apply such a copy rule using `ExportAutoReplacements` in the Option Inspector -- I mention this for anyone reading.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, in v8.

Answer (score 5):

[Sometimes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6962/193) I find this kind of "coding style" in snippets

```
  Return[(b - a)/2 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(weights\), \(i, 2\)]\ f[
\*FractionBox[\(a + b\), \(2\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\(b - a\), \(2\)] 
\*SubscriptBox[\(weights\), \(i, 1\)]]\)\)]];
```

While the following is roughly the same, and much more readable as a mathematica.stackexchange snippet:

```
% /. Subscript[a_, b__] :> a[[b]] // InputForm
(* ->
Return[((-a + b)*Sum[f[(a + b)/2 + ((-a + b)*weights[[i,1]])/2]*weights[[i,2]],{i, 1, n}])/2]
*)
```

Of course there is no problem if you have Mma at hand and copy/paste the code, but when you are reading the Q without access to the front end, decoding the `<Esc>...<Esc>` notation adds *some* neural overhead.

I think we should encourage users to use the cleaner possible code in their examples, which must be thought for posting here and not as a lazy pasting of their actual program.

Answer (score 3):

I have no qualms at all replacing special characters, as long as it doesn't change the behavior of the code.